# SAS Enviromental variable Issue

Tags: sas

Please help me to resolve the issue. issue with `SAS` deployment on `HP UNIX`

```
        server :- Hp unix
        user= sas

    while executing schedule job in sas management console We found below error in
        /SASWORK/ediserver/Lev1/Logs/STG_CONTROL_STATS_PRE_PROD_TEST_SRC_XTC_LD_STG_CONTROL_STATISTICS_PRE_PROD_ 

   ******************************************************************************
2           * Job:             SRC_XTC_LD_STG_CONTROL_STATISTICS       A5LO570L.BB000482 *
3           * Description:                                                               *
4           *                                                                            *
5           * Metadata Server: 10.11.32.205                                              *
6           * Port:            8561                                                      *
7           * Location:        /Users/tcsdev/My Folder/UTI_PRE_PROD/UTI_STG              *
8           *                                                                            *
9           * Server:          SASApp                                  A5LO570L.AR000002 *
10          *                                                                            *
11          * Source Table:    ControlStatistics -                     A5LO570L.BP00003D *
12          *                  /SASWORK/unnati/SASTCS_DAILY_LOAD/KAR                     *
13          *                  VY/ControlStatistics                                      *
14          * Target Table:    STG_CONTROL_STATISTICS -                A5LO570L.BJ0003WN *
15          *                   prepdstg.STG_CONTROL_STATISTICS                          *
16          *                                                                            *
17          * Generated on:    Wednesday, January 13, 2016 3:44:37 PM IST                *
18          * Generated by:    tcsdev                                                    *
19          * Version:         SAS Data Integration Studio 4.21                          *
20          ******************************************************************************/

Error in file

ERROR: Could not load /SASINST/SAS/SASFoundation/9.2/sasexe/sasora (54 images loaded)
ERROR: Unable to find library 'libclntsh.so.10.1'.
107        LIBNAME &STG_LIB_STR;
ERROR: The SAS/ACCESS Interface to ORACLE cannot be loaded. ERROR: Image SASORA   found but not loadable.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

File content for reference

```
        #cat /SASINST/SAS/SASFoundation/9.2/bin/sasenv_local

        #!/bin/sh -p
        #
        # This file is used to define local environment variables that are used
        # with SAS.  These values will override the default values in sasenv.
        # User modifications made to this file will NOT be overwritten by the SAS
        # installation program as the system default values file are.


        ORA_HOME=/SASINST/OraHome_1
            export ORA_HOME

        ORACLE_HOME=/SASINST/ODBC/OraHome_1
        export ORACLE_HOME

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/SASINST/SAS/DataFluxIntegrationServer/8.1/etc:/SASINST/OraHome_1/lib:/SASINST/SAS/SASFoundation/9.2/sasexe
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

profile File content for reference

```
 cat /home/sas/.profile

        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/SASINST/SAS/DataFluxIntegrationServer/8.1/etc:/SASINST/OraHome_1/lib:/SASINST/SAS/SASFoundation/9.2/sasexe
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: May indicate the Oracle module isn't installed or licensed on your machine/server.

Comment: Run `PROC SETINIT` and check to see if ACCESS/Oracle is licensed.  I agree with @ChrisJ that it sounds like you are not licensed.

Comment: If the job is not running under your user id, then you need to check the access of the service/account id the job runs under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Install and configure LSF and PM again and issue get resolve...
```